# Add Custom Variable to Laravel Error Log

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to log the user's name along with the error that is outputted to the log.  How do I add a variable to the beginning of an error log entry that outputs an exception?

Comment: Do you want to do that for every error log or just the one?

Comment: Every log entry.  That way I can identify who initiated the error. For example it says `[2015-10-17 08:33:54] development.ERROR: `

I'd like `[2015-10-17 08:33:54] development.ERROR [johndoe]:`

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got a fairly easy way to do this.

### Solution 1

Create a new folder under `app` called `handlers` and create a new class called `CustomStreamHandler.php` which will hold the custom monolog handler.

```
namespace App\Handlers;

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Auth;

class CustomStreamHandler extends StreamHandler
{
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        $record['context']['user'] = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : 'guest';

        parent::write($record);
    }
}
```

Make sure you set the namespace if you changed it from `App` and also modify the line where it's setting the user in the context so it works with your users table.

Now we need to drop the current `StreamHandler` from monolog.  Laravel sets this up by default and as far as I can see, there isn't a good way to stop Laravel from doing this.

in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`, we should modify the `boot()` function to do remove the handler and insert the new one.  Add the following...

```
// Get the underlying instance of monolog
$monolog = \Log::getMonolog();

// Instantiate a new handler.
$customStreamHandler = new \App\Handlers\CustomStreamHandler(storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));

// Set the handlers on monolog.  Note this would remove all existing handlers.
$monolog->setHandlers([$customStreamHandler]);
```

### Solution 2

This is a much easier solution but also not exactly what you are looking for (but it might still work for you).

Add the following to `AppServiceProvider.php` `boot()`.

```
Log::listen(function()
{
    Log::debug('Additional info', ['user' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : 'guest']);
});
```

This will simply listen for any logging and also log a debug line containing user information.

Comment: Have any solutions for this in a 5.X stack? Dealing with it currently.