# Passing optional custom parameter with Laravel (Monolog) logging

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I have a Laravel project.  I would like to pass an optional custom parameter (domain ID) when creating log entries.  I am logging to a MySQL database via a custom Monolog event handler,  [based on this tutorial:](https://github.com/markhilton/monolog-mysql/blob/master/src/Logger/Monolog/Handler/MysqlHandler.php).

I have searched but cannot find any solutions for what appears to be a relatively simple problem, there's a number of posts discussing things like [adding user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268815/add-custom-variable-to-laravel-error-log) but none consider a simple optional parameter.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Laravel: 8.27
PHP:     8.0.2

As per the tutorial, I have configured a custom handler and I can see how to use session variables or similar for customer

As per the tutorial, I have this custom handler:

```
namespace App\Logging;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
class MySQLLoggingHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler{

    public function __construct($level = Logger::DEBUG, $bubble = true) {
        parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
    }
    protected function write(array $record):void
    {
        $remote_addr = '127.0.0.1';
        if (isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
        $user_agent = 'Unknown';
        if (isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];}
        $data = array(
            'message'       => $record['message'],
            'context'       => json_encode($record['context']),
            'level'         => $record['level'],
            'level_name'    => $record['level_name'],
            'channel'       => $record['channel'],
            'record_datetime' => $record['datetime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'extra'         => json_encode($record['extra']),
            'formatted'     => $record['formatted'],
            'remote_addr'   => $remote_addr,
            'user_agent'    => $user_agent,
            'created_at'    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        );
        DB::connection()->table('log_entries')->insert($data);
    }
}
```

And the custom logger class that uses it:

```
namespace App\Logging;
use Monolog\Logger;
class MySQLCustomLogger{
    /**
     * Custom Monolog instance.
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config){
        $logger = new Logger("MySQLLoggingHandler");
        return $logger->pushHandler(new MySQLLoggingHandler());
    }
}
```

The above works great for pushing logs to the database like this:

`Log::info("New record created for domain id".$domain_id);`

Unfortunately this makes searching the database painful when looking for enties for a specific ID, I was hoping to be able to add an option parameter like this:

`Log::info("New record created for domain", $domain_id);`

Comment: Sorry, typo in "customer" should be custom but I cannot edit at the moment ("An error occurred submitting the edit.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log the following way

```
Log::info('New record created for domain id', ['domain_id' => $domain_id]);
```

This should be accessible on the extra parameter on the array.

```
protected function write(array $record):void
{
    ...

    $data = [
        ...
        'domain_id' => $record['context']['domain_id'],
    ];
```

For a better understanding, the `$record` is actually a type of [Log Record](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/LogRecord.php), which will help understanding what capabilities the `$record` property has.

Comment: Thansk @mrhn, I tried the above and I get the following error:Undefined array key "domain_id".  It works fine if I just push a number directly in to the domain_id field w

Comment: dd($record['extra']);  in the handler returns an empty array [ ]

Comment: What if you change the typehint from array to LogRecord and dd($record->extra);

Comment: So it turns out I had to do $record['context']['domain_id'] to retrieve the value - thanks for the hint!

Comment: great it helped i updated the answer to help others in the future